# How to print the key of highest value from the list's element of the dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary, bioinformatics, consensus

I am still new to python so apologies in advance if my question is confusing.
I have this

```
A  :  [5, 1, 0, 0, 5, 5, 0]
C  :  [0, 1, 1, 2, 1, 0, 2]
G  :  [0, 3, 2, 1, 0, 1, 2]
T  :  [1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1]
```

dictionary. I want to print the ***key*** of the highest value from the list.
For eg:-  From the first element of the list i.e. 5,0,0,1
***A*** has the highest value i want to print A, then for second position its ***G*** and so on.

Thank you.

Edited: -  Hey guys thank you for all your advice I was able to complete the task.

Comment: Hey Nikhil! Can you show us what you have tried so far? What's the desired behavior when there are two entries with the same max number?

Comment: Actually I have am trying to solve Bioinformatics problem from Rosalind. The current problems requires me to find a consensus sequences from given sequences.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following:

```
d = {"A": [5, 1, 0, 0, 5, 5, 0],
     "C": [0, 1, 1, 2, 1, 0, 2],
     "G": [0, 3, 2, 1, 0, 1, 2],
     "T": [1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1]}

maxes = [max(d, key=lambda k: d[k][i]) for i in range(len(list(d.values())[0]))]
# ['A', 'G', 'G', 'C', 'A', 'A', 'C']
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you data is in a dictionary (and it's named `d`), you can try:

```
maxkey = max(d.items(), key=lambda x: max(x[1]))[0]
print(maxkey)
```

Output:

```
A
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
>>> def f(di, index):
...     max = None
...     for key in di:
...             if index >= len(di[key]):
...                     continue
...             if max is None or di[max][index] < di[key][index]:
...                     max = key
...     return max
>>> di = {'A': [5, 1, 0, 0, 5, 5, 0],
... 'B': [0, 1, 1, 2, 1, 0, 2]}
>>> f(di, 0)
'A'
>>> f(di, 3)
'B'
```

Answer (score 0):

For each index (0 to 6) get the key that has the maximum value at that index.  That can be done in a list comprehension:

```
[ max(d,key=lambda k:d[k][i]) for i in range(7)] 

['A', 'G', 'G', 'C', 'A', 'A', 'C']
```

If you have different lists sizes in your dictionary or you don't know the length of the lists in advance, you can get it first using the min function:

```
minLen     = min(map(len,d.values()))
maxLetters = [ max(d,key=lambda k:d[k][i]) for i in range(minLen)]
```

*you need to use min() in order to make sure d[k][i] will not go beyond the size of the shortest list.*